# Getting error when creating a new Dynamic Project in JSP using Ecplise IDE 2019

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a new project in Eclipse 2019, I always get this error. Tried changing workspace, but nothing worked for me. What to do now?

[image: Ecplise IDE Error]